# How does one use Expect with Git interactive CLI w/out resorting to alternative strategies?

Tags: expect

Typically, I can use the `expect` mechanic of `expect` followed by `send`.  In the case of `git`'s interactive shell, however, this does not work and I must use `puts`.

Is there some trick to restore the normal usage of the shell? Or could this be a cross-platform issue on Mac that would not exist were I on a linux machine?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# get the expected count
set ct [exec git status | grep -e {deleted by us:} | awk {END{print NR}}]
puts "expect count = $ct"

spawn bash
send "git mergetool\r"
for {set i 0} {$i < $ct} {incr i} {
  expect -re "^.*local.: (.*)$"
  set choice $expect_out(1,string)
  set choice_letter [string index $choice 0]
  expect -re ".*Use.*\?.*" { puts "$choice_letter\r" }  # here I have to use puts, weird
}
```

Is this some bizarre mac thing, or have I learned normal, regular expect behavior and am properly using `puts` instead of `send` in this automatic script?

Comment: I don't have an expect explanation for you. What is the actual merge.tool you're using?

Comment: What I wound up doing was running `autoexpect`, and it seems as if I need to "expect" to see the send values and then "expect" to see the command prompt return. I'll post the answer. @glennjackman

Comment: Parenthetically, you don't need to spawn bash, you can `spawn git mergetool` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up recording an expect macro via `autoexpect`.  Although the result from `autoexpect` is highly literal and brittle, I figured it would get the send mechanic correct.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# get the expected count
set ct [exec git status | awk {BEGIN{count=0} /deleted by us:|added by them:/{count++} END{print count}}]
if { $ct < 1 } { exit 0 }

# set write mode on all of the files
exec git status | grep -e {deleted by us:} -e {added by them:} | cut -d: -f 2 | xargs -n 1 chmod +w

set favor local
puts "favor: $favor"
puts "Deleted file count = $ct"
spawn bash
send "git mergetool\r"
for {set i 0} {$i < $ct} {incr i} {
  expect -re "^.*$favor.: (\[a-z\]+)" {
      set choice $expect_out(1,string) ;
      set choice_letter [string index $choice 0] ;
  }
  expect -re "Use.*\? "
  send "d\r"
  expect "d\r"
}
expect -re ".*"
send -- "^D"
expect eof
```

Where the new additions are at the end:

```
  ...
  expect -re "Use.*\? "
  send "d\r"

  # this line caused things to start working
  expect "d\r"
}
expect -re ".*". # expect the prompt here. 
# The lack of specificity introduces a rare bug, 
# ...but it is also simple and mostly works. 

# this was in the autoexpect recording, and I left it in
# ...probably unnecessary
send -- "^D"

# this was also in autoexpect recording; might be important
expect eof
```

My guess is the git CLI is able to restrict operations to the very last second, and if the terminal hosting it closes up, the operations don't actually take place.  So waiting on the results via the extra `expect` calls might ensure the operation happens.

In a rare case (I am rebasing approx. 2000 of my commits that became disconnected from my main branch history, so approx 1/200), git has some alternative outputs it tacks on the end of its merge prompt that break the automation.

This is due to the `(.*)` match in the expect for the next line of prompt.